# Bootstrap 4 - Collapse and Scrollspy

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have some elements on my web site which use collapse. I want to implement a link to that elements in my menu. When the link will be pressed I want the element to collapse and to focus on it.

I cant get both of these actions to work. When I remove data-toggle from the following line:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#collapsegs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsegs" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsegs">
    Home
</a>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headinggs">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
             <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsegs" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsegs">
                 open
             </button>
        </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapsegs" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headinggs" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
```

then the scrollspy works but the collapse doesn't.

Comment: Please post *all* of the relevant code that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">Collapse One</a>


<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Collapse Two</a>


<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#collapseThree" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">Collapse Three</a>

<br/><br/>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
          Body 1 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Body 2 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
         Body 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```